# How to add additional message when dial view popped out

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertview, phone-call

Is is possible to add any customised message when this popped out? Like `UIAlertView` does.

[image]

Comment: No, there is no public API for modifying that alert.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by customized message?

Comment: @MiloGosnell like customised `UIAlertView` does

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.

But you can do one thing use custom alert and on the delegate method use the `tel` function.

With the `tel` function system alert will not come. and it will directly call the number.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@",strNumber]]];
```